# All Time Machine backups appended with ".interrupted"

Tags: command-line, backup, time-machine

After getting my new MacBook Pro, I formatted a 1 TB drive as APFS to use as my backup disk. After formatting, I noticed some strange behavior after doing backups. I tried to investigate the backup drive, but found no files in it, although a few hundred gigabytes were being used up. I decided to use the terminal to look at what was taking up all this space. This is what I found:

[image]

So it looked like all of my backups were appended with `.interrupted`, suggesting that not a single backup from all these backups had completed successfully. This is what my Time Machine preferences pane looks like:

[image]

Why are all of my backups "interrupted?" How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Me too, roughly: backup disk is APFS over AFP, recent backups are `.interrupted`.  But for me, old backups appear in Finder, but not Terminal - which is even weirder than the revere.
See: 
https://eclecticlight.co/2020/05/09/how-to-check-the-integrity-of-files-in-a-time-machine-backup/ . This site has useful resources; that page suggests that if the appropriate `sudo tmutil verifychecksums /Volumes...` command returns nothing <sic>, then your backups are OK, which addresses a part of your question/concern.  So far, it worked on small subdirectories I tried it on.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about these folders and don't try to clean them up manually. All files and data from interrupted backups are not copied again on the next backup try (provided they were not changed), Time Machine would verify and use them. And it will clean up the ".interrupted" folders automatically after finishing the 1st successful backup.

Comment: What if there never is a successfull backups?

Comment: Then, by these files, you can see that it tried to back up, how often and when and how much it could do in one try.